# Cauchy’s theorem for triangles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

So I’m reading a proof a proof for Cauchy’s theorem for triangles. That is if $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is analytic and $\Delta $ is a triangle in open $U $ with boundary $\gamma $ ($U$ contains $\gamma $ too). Then $$\int_{\gamma }f(z)\ dz=0 .$$

The proof basically iteratively splits the triangle into 4 smaller triangles and uses the triangles with the greatest value of the integral.
Anyway, you have a point $z_*$ which is in $\overline{\Delta }$ and because $f$ is differentiable there we can say for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0 $ such that if $|z-z_* |<\delta $ then $$f(z)=f(z_*)+f’(z_*)(z-z_*)+R(z,z_*) $$ where $|R(z,z_*)|<\epsilon |z-z_*|.$

So $$|\int_{\gamma^{(n)}}f(z)\ dz |=|\int_{\gamma^{(n)}} R(z,z_*) \ dz| .$$

**So the question I’m ask asking is, what happened to** $\int f(z_*)\ dz $ and $\int f’(z_*)(z-z_*)\ dz $ ?
**What’s the justification for them integrals being 0?**

Comment: any integral $\int_\gamma (Az+B)\,dz$ over a closed contour is zero as $Az+B$ is a derivative.

Comment: So you can say that any function analytic $f$ has antiderivative $F$ then the integral is 0 over a closed contour?

Comment: Doesn’t any function have antiderivative? Obviously it can’t do can it because cauchys theorem would be trivial I guess?

Comment: It's Goursat's lemma: see a proof p. 40 of this document: https://math.unm.edu/~lorenz/561/h.pdf

Comment: $1/z$ doesn't have an antiderivative in any puctured neighbourhood of the origin.